# Tensorflow Probability (TFP): BNN Image classifier not learning with OneHotCategorical layer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability, image-classification

I am fooling around with TFP, but can't get it to learn when using OneHotCategorical as the final layer. However, if my final layer is a Dense layer with softmax it works fine.

I am quite new to TFP so I have probably missed something.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bPQSymgAO9VFPCct0qF5IDKsscv6b55v?usp=sharing

Any suggestions?

Best regards,
Måns

Comment: Please add your code to the question so users dont have to go to an outside site to answer the question.
Neverthless, in your loss function you feed the model output as logits. If you have OneHotCategorical as your output layer these are no longer logits?

Comment: [Check this out](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/main/tensorflow_probability/examples/bayesian_neural_network.py)